# Image source not readable with Laravel Image Intervention

Tags: php, html, image, laravel, intervention

So this has been a problem for me for a while now and it just doesn't seem to work, I have a form where users can submit a new profile picure:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/profile" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="avatar">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <input type="submit" class="pull-right btn btn-sm btn-primary">
</form>
```

When the button is clicked they are being redirected to the controller which activates the following function:

```
public function update_avatar(Request $request)
{
    $avatar = $request->avatar;
    $extension = File::extension($avatar);
    $filename = time() . '.' . $extension;
    Image::make($avatar)->resize(350, 350)->save( public_path('/uploads/avatars/' . $filename ) );

    $user = Sentinel::getUser();
    $user->profile->avatar = $filename;
    $user->save();
}
```

But whatever I do the controller always returns the message

> (1/1) NotReadableException
>
> Image source not readable

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

**EDIT:** I've changed my Image::make line to the following:

```
$image = Image::make($avatar->getRealPath())->resize(350, 350)->save( public_path('/uploads/avatars/' . $filename ) );
```

But now I am encountering a new error:

> (1/1) FatalErrorException
>
> Call to a member function getRealPath() on string

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead :

```
Image::make($avatar->getRealPath())->resize(350, 350)->save( public_path('/uploads/avatars/' . $filename ) );
```

**Edit:**
use this, to retrieve your UploadedFile

```
$avatar = $request->file('avatar');
```

**Edit #2:**
For the extension use this instead :

```
$extension = $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

**Note:** Do not forget to authorize only images files in your validation rules.

Intead, you can "hardcode" the extension, Intervention is able to save & convert into the specified image format (jpg, png ..)

Comment: It gets rid of the first error but now it displays:

**(1/1) FatalErrorException
Call to a member function getRealPath() on string**

Comment: You have to change the way you retrieve your uploaded file. I've edited my post.

Comment: When I include your **Edited** method I get an array of data when dd'ing the avatar but now I get an error that the encoding format is not supported: **Encoding format (tmp) is not supported.** means it's getting a tmp file instead of the .jpg file

Comment: I fixed it, I included the function getClientOriginalName(); but it is still giving me the 'string' error message

Comment: I've edited again, keep using getRealPath(), because intervention needs the uploaded file's 'tmp_name' [See docs](http://image.intervention.io/use/uploads)